# Adjust/scale a detrended time series to an arbitrary time period

Tags: time-series

Suppose I have detrended my data by using the residuals from a simple OLS time trend model. So for $t = 1, 2, ...T$, the detrended series $z_t$ is defined as below,

$y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1t + \epsilon_t$

$z_t = y_t - \widehat{y_t}$

Now to adjust (or I guess "scale") the detrended series to a particular time period, can I simply add the value for that period? For example, if I want all the values to be adjusted to time period $t = 20$, would the series be:

$z_t + y_{20}$

Does this extend to the panel data case? Where now, you would use the mean value of observations at $t = 20$, of the form

$z_{ti} + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{y_{i20}}{n}$

Thanks, this seems pretty basic but while there's a lot of resources on detrending time series, I struggled to find anything related to my question

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "adjusting a time series to a particular time period", especially in reference to your t values of 1, 2, ..., T?

Comment: The detrending method I showed leads to a residual time series with mean zero, so I want to think about the time trend being removed, but the magnitude of the observations remain. So if there has been an upward trend up to time T, I want to think about the past observations being adjusted upwards. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know sometimes people 'center' the value of t around some meaningful temporal landmark (e.g., t = 20) in their trend model:

```
y[t] = beta0 + beta1*(t-20) + epsilon[t].
```

In this case, beta0 has a more meaningful interpretation - it represents the expected value of y when t = 20.

I guess you can "detrend" the value of y[t] like so:

```
z[t] = y[t]  - (estimated beta1)*(t-20)
```

which would then leave you with "residuals" centered about the value (estimated beta0). In other words, the "residuals" would be centered about the level of the series y corresponding to t = 20.

Not sure this is what you want?

Addendum:

I added a plot which illustrates the various possibilities.

In panel 1 a) of the plot, you see the original data plotted via a scatterplot which shows y on the vertical axis and t on the horizontal one.

In panel 1 b), you see the detrended version of y (called z in your notation) plotted against t, where z was obtained as z = y - b0 - b1*t, where b0 and b1 are the estimated slope and intercept describing the trend line seen in panel 1 a).

In panel 1 c), you see the detrended version of y (that is, z) shifted upward by an amount given by b0 + b1*(20).  The level of this "detrended + shifted upward" version of y is given by b0 + b1*(20).

All three panels 1 a), 1 b) and 1 c) use the same vertical scale for ease of comparison and display a vertical line going through t = 20 as well as a horizontal line going through b0 + b1*(20).

Panels 2 a), 2 b) and 2 c) show similar plots except that their horizontal axis no longer corresponds to t but rather to (t - 20).  In particular:

Panel 2 a) of the plot shows the scatterplot of y versus t - 20.

Panel 2 b) shows the detrended version of y (namely, z) plotted against t - 20, where z was obtained as z = y - b00 - b11*(t-20), where b00 and b11 are the estimated slope and intercept describing the trend line seen in panel 2 a), which was obtained by regressing y against t - 20.

Panel 1 c) shows the detrended version of y (that is, z) shifted upward by an amount given by b00 + b11*(20-20).  The level of this "detrended + shifted upward" version of y is given by b00 + b11*(20-20).   Note that b00 + b11*(20-20) = b00 + b11*0 = b00.

In principle, you can use either the method in panel 1 c) or the method in panel 2c) to "detrend y and then shift its detrended version upward/downward by a certain amount". For both methods, the amount by which you do the shifting can be computed from the linear trend model as:

```
(1)  b0 + b1*(20) for the first method; 
(2)  b00 + b11*(20-20) for the second method.
```

The sign of the amounts shown in items (1) and (2) above determines whether the shift will be performed upward (positive sign) or downward (negative sign).

The amounts in (1) and (2) themselves correspond to the level of the original series y when: 
     (1) t = 20 for the first method; 
     (2) t - 20 = 0 for the second method.

I guess the interpretation of the vertical scale in panels 1 c) and 2 c) is a bit trickier.  For panels 1 b) and 2 b), the vertical scale corresponds to the **detrended version of y**.  For panels 1 c) and 2 c), the vertical scale corresponds to the **detrended and then shifted upward/downward version of y**.

[image]